# MassTransit doesn't create queue/subscription when configured in a lambda

Tags: .net, aws-lambda, masstransit

The following code works great on an API.

```
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<RelationshipCreatedConsumer>();

    x.UsingAmazonSqs((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host(new Uri("amazonsqs://localhost:4566"), h =>
        {
            h.AccessKey("your-iam-access-key");
            h.SecretKey("your-iam-secret-key");

            h.Config(new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceConfig { ServiceURL = "http://host.docker.internal:4566" });
            h.Config(new AmazonSQSConfig { ServiceURL = "http://host.docker.internal:4566" });
        });

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("rc_queue", e =>
        {
            e.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Interval(2, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000)));

            e.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
            e.Subscribe(nameof(RelationshipCreated));

            e.ConfigureConsumer<RelationshipCreatedConsumer>(context);
        });

        cfg.Message<RelationshipCreated>(top =>
        {
            top.SetEntityName(nameof(RelationshipCreated));
        });

    });
});
```

In this setup, consumer is also located in the API. I want to extract it to an Lambda function. So I removed `AddConsumer` and `ReceiveEndpoint` calls from the code abone. Now my API is able to publish a message and create a topic when needed. Great.

Following is the code I created for my Lambda function:

```
public class Function
{
    private ServiceProvider _provider;

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor. This constructor is used by Lambda to construct the instance. When invoked in a Lambda environment
    /// the AWS credentials will come from the IAM role associated with the function and the AWS region will be set to the
    /// region the Lambda function is executed in.
    /// </summary>
    public Function()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ok");

        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.AddConsumer<RelationshipCreatedConsumer>();
            x.UsingAmazonSqs((context, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.Host(new Uri("amazonsqs://localhost:4566"), h =>
                {
                    h.AccessKey("your-iam-access-key");
                    h.SecretKey("your-iam-secret-key");

                    h.Config(new AmazonSQSConfig { ServiceURL = "http://host.docker.internal:4566" });
                    h.Config(new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceConfig { ServiceURL = "http://host.docker.internal:4566" });
                });

                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(queueName: "dummy", e =>
                {
                    e.Subscribe(nameof(RelationshipCreated));
                    e.ConfigureConsumer<RelationshipCreatedConsumer>(context);
                });

                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
            });
        });

        _provider = services.BuildServiceProvider(true);
    }

    public class RelationshipCreatedConsumer : IConsumer<RelationshipCreated>
    {
        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<RelationshipCreated> context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("YUS");
            // TODO: write something to S3
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// This method is called for every Lambda invocation. This method takes in an SNS event object and can be used 
    /// to respond to SNS messages.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="evnt"></param>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task FunctionHandler(RelationshipCreated evnt, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("YUS2");
        var consumer = _provider.GetRequiredService<IConsumer<RelationshipCreated>>();
        return;
    }
}
```

I expected the code above to create a queue called dummy and subscribe to the topic created by the API. None of those happen and also there are no errors. I executed the lambda via http call so the constructor is executed.

What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: Is this dockerised?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Yes. Localstack, API & lambda runs in separate containers build from one docker-compose.

Comment: But you don't have Localstack in your Lambda function - why are you referring to localhost in your Lambda code?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. Are you referring to localhost in `cfg.Host(new Uri("amazonsqs://localhost:4566"), h =>`? I just updated it to host.docker.internal:4566 but result is still the same. It is also localhost in API but somehow that works perfectly.

Comment: It works perfectly in your local API? Of course, you can't be calling localhost:4566 in your Lambda function.

Comment: API is also in container. I also tested with changing lamda config to localhost everywhere and running it locally outside of container but still no result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-LambdaFunction) showing how to use MassTransit consumers within AWS Lambda functions (triggered by SQS). I'd suggest using it to build your consumer functions.

And, of course, MassTransit doesn't create the queue since it must exist before you can register the Lambda trigger. When used in functions (Lambda, or Azure Functions), MassTransit is not the transport, just the pipeline/dispatch engine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chris. I did check that a few times. To try; I created the queue myself before running the lambda but still no subscription created between the topic and the queue. Clearly I'm missing something here, I'll dig deeper.

Comment: MassTransit isn't going to create queues, topics, or subscriptions for you with Lambda. It's just how it is, all that stuff is created by MassTransit when it's in a host, to launch the hosted services.

Comment: Aha, now it makes a lot of sense. I was expecting same behavior as the API. Thanks for the explanation.